# PSPDFKit iOS 8 PSPDFGlobalLock documentProviderForDocument:page:

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, pspdfkit

I've a magazine app that downloads PDF in `/Library/Caches/...` It works pretty well with **iOS 7**, but from **iOS 8** ( that changes file system directories ) I can't open downloaded PDF! from `PSPDFKit` log error I see:

> **File downloaded path**:

```
/Users/steven/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxxxx/data/Containers/Data/Application/xxxxx/Library/Caches/doc1.pdf
```

> **PSPDFkit set document from path error**:

```
Error: -[PSPDFGlobalLock documentProviderForDocument:page:]/248 Cannot get document reference, there is no file at /Users/steven/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxxxx/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxx/[NAMEAPP]/Users/steven/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxxxx/data/Containers/Data/Application/xxxx/Library/Caches/doc1.pdf!
```

Attention: I've replaced some words with **xxxx**

I'm using an old version of `PSPDFKit`( i don't known exactly version, I can't find version params )

**i get "Caches" folder in this way ( called [Utility documents] in my code )**:

```
NSArray *paths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES )];

return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

**Download path PDF code:**

```
NSString *destPath = [[Utility documents] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[highlightedMagazine objectForKey:@"url"] lastPathComponent]];
```

**Read PDF code for iOS 8:**

```
NSString *destPath = [[Utility documents] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[highlightedMagazine objectForKey:@"url"] lastPathComponent]];

pdfController.document = (PSPDFDocument *)[[Utility documents] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[highlightedMagazine objectForKey:@"url"] lastPathComponent]];
```

I see also that download path is `"/data/Containers/Data"` and read path is `"/data/Containers/Bundle"`, I can't change it.

Can someone help me?? Thank you!

Comment: so you confirm that is a problem of PSPDFKit lib and not my code?

Comment: I can't confirm it - we didn't test v1 or v2 against iOS 8.

Comment: ok thank you, but with my current code e new lib my apps will work or i have to change some code to support v4? i wrote to 'sales' last friday, but at time anyone answer to me, can you notify it to your staff? it's urgent! i need to upgrade immediatly!

Comment: I've made sure to expedite this.